# Jquery animate, how to make it animate on click of link and on load of page

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

ljessett.hndcomputing.net/lewis

when you first visit the homepage nothing happens

click home and the page will animate how do i make this page animate like when a link is clicked on load

the jquery dynamically changes the content of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the animation code inside a named function, so you can call the function both on load of the page and on the click of the link.

```
function animation() {

    // your animation code here...

}
```

Then call it on windows load

```
$(window).load(function() {

    // call animation function
    animation();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function() {
  $('#menu li:eq(0) a').click();
});
```